# How to get the contexts values

Tags: node.js, actions-on-google

I am new to develop google assistant apps. I'm saving some data in contexts but I'm not getting the value of the context as per required.
Here below is my code:

```
const AppContexts = {
  NUMBER: 'userConfigData',
}

conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.NUMBER, 5,AppContexts)
const value = conv.contexts.get(AppContexts.NUMBER)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to refer to Dialogflow. Under the following [link](https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/classes/dialogflow.contextvalues.html) you can find examples on how to set and get contents:

[image]

Try  `conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.NUMBER, 5)`, as used in the sample, 
 instead of `conv.contexts.set(AppContexts.NUMBER, 5,AppContexts)`.

If you check Google documentation for [Dialogflow](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.agent.sessions.contexts), you will see that the content of the `conv.contentexts.set()` method should be:

```
{
  "name": string,
  "lifespanCount": number,
  "parameters": {
    object
  }
}
```

I believe AppContexts is not a valid parameter.